# Flutter audio_service implement skipToNext without queue

Tags: flutter, audio, notifications

I have a long audio file that has different sections.
I have a `Map` containing where those sections start.

I want to implement `skipToNext()` and `skipToPrevious` methods for it.

I have access to the map inside `BackgroundAudioTask`.

I have implemented `onSkipToNext` like this:

```dart
 @override
  Future<void> onSkipToNext() async => () {
        print('next pressed');
        final currentIndex = _getCurrentTrackIndex(_player.position);
        print(currentIndex);
        if (currentIndex < _tracks.length - 1) {
          _player.seek(
            Duration(milliseconds: _tracks[currentIndex + 1]['start']),
          );
        }
      };
```

The `_tracks` looks like this:

```
[{id: 1, title: INTRODUCTION, start: 0}, {id: 2, title: Next track, start: 68347},]
```

But when I press on `MediaControl.skipToNext` from the notification or
`AudioService.skipToNext();` from Flutter UI.

It is not working i.e `next pressed` is not showing in the console and the audio is not working.

Am I doing something wrong?
Can't I press `MediaControl.skipToNext` if there is no queue?

If I cannot do so, how can I implement such a feature?

Note: I am using `just_audio` for playing audio

Edit: Here's my `systemActions`

```
systemActions: [
  MediaAction.seekTo,
  MediaAction.seekForward,
  MediaAction.seekBackward,
  MediaAction.skipToNext,
  MediaAction.skipToPrevious,
],
```

Solved: Incorrect implementation of `onSkipToNext()` was the case of the problem as the accepted answer suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything else works and it's just these two skip actions that don't work, the first thing you will need to do is include `skipToNext` and `skipToPrevious` in the `controls` parameter of `AudioServiceBackground.setState` rather than `systemActions`. `systemActions` is only for things that are not clickable buttons (e.g. `seekTo`).

You must also pass `androidEnableQueue: true` to `AudioService.start` if you want these queue-skipping actions to work on Android.

For completeness, I'll also just mention that none of the notification buttons (or headset buttons) will work on Android unless you have declared the broadcast receiver in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
        <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But aside from all of those things, I notice your code contains a subtle programming error that is unrelated to audio_service. Your implementation of `onSkipToNext` simply returns a closure `() { ... }` so even if this callback is being called, the code inside the closure isn't being called. So you need to replace `=> () { ... }` by `{ ... }`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. But I have already tried these. I have created a simple repo to reproduce this issue. Can you please have a look at it and point out if I am doing something wrong? https://github.com/paurakhsharma/audio_service_example

Comment: My original answer covered all of the known issues related specifically to `onSkipToNext` and `onSkipToPrevious`, so if you've done all of those, then your `onSkipToNext` method is being called. I've edited my answer with another point which is that even though your `onSkipToNext` method may be called, you've written it as a closure where the inner code never gets executed.

Comment: Thanks, man, incorrect method implementation was the cause of the issue.